# Error processing XSLT stylesheet using Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, encoding

I've made an XSLT application that transforms XML data into a form, that when used, generates modified XML to create a new XML with changes, but without the need of users manipulation XML directly.  Basically display a form and then, with javascript, generate the modified XML.

It just works fine but now comes the weird problem.  I create XML file in server and store it to a file.  If user opens that file into IE, sees the error:

Can't display XML page
Access denied.  Error processing resource.

Now, if i open and just "save" the same xml file, when opened again on IE XML gets transformed as expected.

I suspect this is an encoding problem, but source XML and XSLT, content-type and so are all set to ISO-8859-1 and now I'm a bit lost :(

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: "Access denied" has nothing to do with encodings, rather with the same origin policy applied by browsers preventing access to a resource from one origin by a resource from a different origin. So make sure both XML and XSLT are located at the same origin (e.g. http://example.com/file.xml and http://example.com/sheet.xsl). If you still have problems and that is a public web site then post a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as Dimitre said had nothing to do with encodings, but with a "weird" feature of windows, thats prevents using "dangerous" files that come from another computer.

This happends when you have NTFS in your filesystem and in the remote filesystem from where you got the file.

To avoid this, you can add to "Trusted sites" the web from which you are downloading the file, or you can do it by pressing "left click-> properties-> disable" on a security fieldset...